# How to read Data From Power BI Dataset to Python

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi-desktop

Is there any way to connect to a Power BI dataset and export this data to a Pandas DF?
I've been looking for this online but found nothing except using **adodbapi** which is failing to install on our side due to the **'build_py_2to3'** package and we have not been able to overpass this.

[This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gK0N-AGGn4&t=31s)

We are trying to get this data from a PowerBI dataset as the data comes from different Power BI Dataflows where all transformations are occurring and it is not stored in any DB unfortunately.

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score -1):

By default in power bi when you try to add a python script there is a variable named
'dataset' holds the input data for this script.

Here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd

txt = dataset["COLUMN"]
```

so you can use the variable txt that equal to the column in dataset .

I hope that helps you .